# Is there any data on actual average USPS delivery times

Tags: usa, government, transportation

I'm looking for data on the average delivery times between points for the US Postal Service.  I've found maps on their site with scheduled delivery times but I'm wondering if anyone has data on actual deliveries?

Comment: You may have to file a FOIA request. If you do, I'd be fascinated to see the results. https://about.usps.com/who-we-are/foia/welcome.htm

Answer (score 1):

Yep, as Andrew Said, Though I hate to be a negative nancy, I fear that this is simply not something USPS tracks, so there may not be any quality dataset.